# MariaDB: Operation too slow. Less than 1 bytes/sec transfered the last 30 seconds

Tags: mysql, centos, mariadb, centos7, yum

I'm trying to install mariadb on a centos machine. I'm using following command to do that:

```
sudo yum install mariadb-server
```

I'm getting this error after sometime.

> http://yum.mariadb.org/10.1/centos7-amd64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno
>   12] Timeout on
>   http://yum.mariadb.org/10.1/centos7-amd64/repodata/repomd.xml: (28,
>   'Operation too slow. Less than 1 bytes/sec transfered the last 30
>   seconds')
>
> Trying other mirror.
>
> Error: Cannot retrieve repository
>   metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: mariadb. Please verify its path
>   and try again

If I use `curl` to download the `repomd.xml` file, it is working. But when I'm trying to install it using `yum`, it is giving this error. Any idea on how to overcome this error?

Answer (score -1):

```
perror 12
```

says "OS error code 12: Cannot allocate memory".

So, let's try to see if that is source the second problem.  Some things to provide:

- How much RAM?
- 32-bit or 64-bit OS and MariaDB?
- `top`
- `innodb_buffer_pool_size`